# React adding css class without rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my project I have table, each row has his own class depends on state.
I also have sticked columns so when I do horizontal scroll then some columns are fixed.

My problem is that when some state is changing (eg. from `none` to `rejected`) i need to mark this row as `rejected` className and change background color.

Using `setState` is problematic because whole row is rerendered so my sticky columns are gone (I do calculations on every `scroll` event).

The question is: is there any other solution to change react `className` without rerendering my row? (besides jQuery)

Comment: I'm pretty sure changing state is the right way to do that. Can you trigger your calculations after re-rendering, restoring the view? You can save coordinates if you need them in state as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I found solution.
My each cell in a row has its own component. As you know each element which is creating from array needs to have `key` prop.

```
return (
  <tr>
    {cells.map(cell => (<td key={_.uniqueId()}>{cell.val}</td>))
  </tr>
)
```

I used to be passing lodash's `_.uniqueId()` value - this was causing my problem.
The solution was to replace this unique id with some uniqe string, in my case combiation of two IDs and column name.

So final solution looks like:

```js
return (
  <tr>
    {cells.map(cell => {
      const keyId = `${row.id}${cell.id}${cell.name}`
      return (<td key={keyId}>{cell.val}</td>})
    }}
  </tr>
)
```

Here is explanation why it was destroying and rerendering again:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children

Answer (score 1):

Change the state in your Row component so that the class is updated. Then, use PureComponent (https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/7195) on your child components so that they will not rerender unless their own props changed. Does that solve your problem?